# What does @serviceactivator does exactlly?

Tags: spring-integration

I wish to understand what does serviceactivator annotation do? Because I want to modify message when I got it through serviceactivator. For example I have seen, there is no message parameter I can control. Why handle can receive message, even I cannot see any message parameter passed in, what is the principle?

```
@Bean
@ServiceActivator(inputChannel="requests")
public MessageHandler jmsMessageHandler((ActiveMQConnectionFactory connectionFactory) {
   JmsSendingMessageHandler handler = new JmsSendingMessageHandler(new 
   JmsTemplate(connectionFactory));
   handler.setDestinationName("requests");
   return handler;
}
```

I wish I can do

```
@Bean
@ServiceActivator(inputChannel="requests")
public MessageHandler jmsMessageHandler(Message message) {
   String new_message = message.split();

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `@ServiceActivator` wraps a call to the consumer endpoint. In case of `MessageHandler` it is used as is and the message from the `inputChannel` is passed to it. But if your code is not based on the `MessageHandler`, but is a simple POJO method invocation, then everything is based on the signature of your method. In the end that POJO method call is wrapped to the `MethodInvokingMessageHandler`.

In your case it must be something like this:

```
@ServiceActivator(inputChannel="requests", outputChannel="toJms")
public String jmsMessageHandler(Message message) {
   return message.split();
}
```

So, no `@Bean`, because we deal only with POJO method invocation. The `message` is something incoming from request message and return `String` is going to become a `payload` from output message to processed somewhere downstream on the `toJms` channel.

See more info in the Reference Manual: https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/current/reference/html/#annotations

Comment: I was watching a youtube video(of your lecture about DSL) and then i found this

Comment: is every question about spring integration flow answered by Artem Bilan only?

Comment: Is anything wrong with that? That’s actually a part of my job anyway, so I’m here on SO very often